# How to access filename of executing spec in protractor with jasmine?

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor

for example I start my tests with

```
protractor --specs spec1.js,spec2.js config.js
```

I would like to output "spec1.js" once for each run of spec1-tests, and "spec2.js" once for each run of spec2-tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current filename, there is a generic solution in Nodejs

```
console.log(__filename)
```

You can add this in your spec file to understand the current file being executed

```
var path = require('path');
describe('Locator testing by model', function(){
    var scriptName = path.basename(__filename);
    console.log(__filename) // Output - C:\Users\WebstormProjects\demo\testFileName.js
    console.log(scriptName) // Output - testFileName.js
    it('automate user register form', function(){
        browser.sleep(10000)
        browser.get('http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/registeration/#/login');
        browser.sleep(10000)
    });
});
```

To get the complete list of specs passed through either CLI or from conf.js

```
    browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config){
        console.log(config.specs)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! A combination of the last one with shardTestFalse: true worked for me, as I wanted to get the actual filename of executed specs from conf.js

Comment: Glad that it worked .. can you mark this as answer to close the issue

Comment: Still can't work out how to get the value of config.specs in non-promise (callback function) context:


onSomething: function(){

 browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config){
        console.log(config.specs)
    })
// should return config.specs[0] as a string
return ???
}


Do you have any ideas?
but it is probably a problem for another topic....